# changing strings to integers in a dictionary. python

Tags: python

This is my code, which attempts to change strings in a dict to integers:

```
data1 = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in data.items())
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tanwirshirzai/Desktop/starter files/a6q1_starter.py", line 18, in <module>
    data1=dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in data.items())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

The dictionary in question is this:

```
[['0 to 4 years', '1918924', '1921123', '1924604', '1942022', '1953040'], 
 ['5 to 9 years', '1882687', '1918323', '1952041', '1985144', '2003143'], 
 ['10 to 14 years', '1868495', '1865818', '1864760', '1886340', '1920898']]
```

I am trying to get all the numbers as integers deleting the `'0 to 4 years'`. I succeeded in deleting the first row which is `'0 to 4 years'` but don't know how to convert the numbers to integers.

Comment: The main problem I see is that you're trying to apply a dict operation to a list.  What you posted here is *not* a dictionary.  See your Python language materials for the differentiation.

Comment: other than the list of lists issue, all the items in the list are already strings, so also not sure what you mean by: "am trying to get is all the number as strings"

Comment: You slice all but the first element of each sub-list and apply `int` to each of those.  The methods for these are covered well on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.  Now that you have the right terminology, you should have no trouble finishing the task.

Comment: Prune my bad it is a list of lists and, I meant to say number to integers CasualDemon

Answer (score 0):

That's not a dictionary, it's a list of lists.  Something like:

`[([item[0]] + [int(x) for x in item[1:]]) for item in data]`

should work.

Comment: sorry I meant to say was. those number strings into integers so that I can use them in math equations